# Output category color option to each li item

Tags: categories

Well, I know this might be a noob wordpress question but I am learning :) So here it goes.

I am trying to output the category color scheme from the admin area in my theme. I have this function currently but it doesn't seem to be sending the color code through the output. Any ideas would be of great help. :)

```
function the_category_colors() {

    $categories = get_the_category();
    $color = get_term_meta($category[0]->cat_ID, 'color', true);
  $separator = '';
  $output = '';
  if($categories){

      foreach($categories as $category) {
          $output .= '<div class="cat-span" style="background-color: '. $color .' "><a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a></div>'.$separator;
      }
      echo trim($output, $separator);
  }
```

}

Thanks so much for the help ahead of time :) Let me know if I need to be more clear or this is confusing in any way.

Edit: I forgot to add that everything works fine minus the color being displayed. Hope that helps. :) Thanks!

Comment: no color or all the same color?

Comment: Hi Michael. It actually doesn't show any color at all. When I code it manually it works but when I add it as a function it's broken for some reason ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is stored in the term meta?
a full hex color code like `#123edf`?

your `$color` line seems to be inserted too early, and needs to be adapted;

try:

```
function the_category_colors() {

    $categories = get_the_category();
  $separator = '';
  $output = '';
  if($categories){

      foreach($categories as $category) {
          $output .= '<div class="cat-span" style="background-color: '.     get_term_meta($category->term_id, 'color', true) . '; "><a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a></div>'.$separator;
      }
      echo trim($output, $separator);
  }
}
```

what is the html output of the code in the browser?

Comment: Scratch that Michael! :P I made a stupid mistake haha! Your answer works perfectly. Thank you soooooo much! Made my night :D